# Randomly generated adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r, graph-theory

I'm wanting to generate random connected directed acyclic graphs, and am wondering if there is a way of populating an adjacency matrix in R which would represent the aforementioned.

Something similar to this would be nice (that is done with Mathematica): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/608

Thanks.

Comment: Is the definition of random taken on the other page the one you want? That is, both the number of vertices *and* number if edges are fixed at the outset and a DAG with these properties is generated? Or do you want a *random* number of edges more akin to an Erdos-Renyi model? Also, you mention connected DAGs here but not there. Can you clarify?

Comment: The more control the better. That is, if I can control the number of vertices and edges, it would be nice. The graph needs to be connected.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142021/ (the real question of interest here, I think.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question asks for a random lower triangular binary matrix which represents the edges.  Here is one way, with the number of vertices (as `v`) and number of edges stipulated and edges chosen independently and uniformly among the available ones:

```
DAG.random <- function(v, nedges=1) {
    edges.max <- v*(v-1)/2
    # Assert length(v)==1 && 1 <= v
    # Assert 0 <= nedges <= edges.max
    index.edges <- lapply(list(1:(v-1)), function(k) rep(k*(k+1)/2, v-k)) 
    index.edges <- index.edges[[1]] + 1:edges.max
    graph.adjacency <- matrix(0, ncol=v, nrow=v)
    graph.adjacency[sample(index.edges, nedges)] <- 1
    graph.adjacency
}
```

This solution uses R's simultaneous use of matrix and array indexing.  `index.edges` computes a list of the *array* indexes corresponding to the lower triangular elements of `graph.adjacency`.  (This is done by finding the gaps in these indexes left by the diagonal and upper triangular entries and shifting the sequence `c(1,2,3,...)` by those gaps.)  Sampling the indexes (without replacement) does the trick.

#### Edit

One *ad-hoc* way to create connected DAGs is by adjoining a connected "skeleton" to the random DAG in a way that keeps it acyclic.  For instance, we can create a linear skeleton *post hoc*:

```
set.seed(17)
n <- 6; e <- 4
a <- DAG.random(n, e)
a[seq(from=2, by=n+1, length.out=n-1)] <- 1
```

Here's the adjacency matrix:

```
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0    1    1    0
```

Comment: While I was writing this reply, the question was changed to require connected graphs. This raises the issue of what the distribution ought to be: should every connected DAG be generated equiprobably?  Or should each *isomorphism class* have the same probability?  Or something else?  Some *ad hoc* solutions are evident: e.g., force 1's into the subdiagonal of the adjacency matrix to create a linear chain and then generate a few more random edges; or generate random marked trees and orient them appropriately, then add a few more random edges; etc.

Comment: I am looking for an ad-hoc solution for sure. I am simply wanting to experiment with an algorithm I have created, and need input data. I don't have any experience with graph theory or much experience with R. Do you have code which could make the connected constraint be forced?

Comment: **One-liner**: `DAG.random <- function(v, e) { A <- matrix(0,v,v);
A[lower.tri(A)] <- sample( c(rep(1,e),rep(0,v*(v-1)/2-e) ) ); A }`

Comment: p.s. isn't that sort of cheating w.r.t a "one-liner" when you use all of those semi-colons ;)

Comment: @Macro: Yes. Sort of. And, it spilled over into two lines in the display. So ugly. :)

Comment: I think the connectedness problem will be hard. I have seen people tackle similar problems, like trying to generate random graphs with fixed degree sequences. That turns out to be extremely finicky and the only somewhat feasible methods are approximate (e.g., importance sampling). Also, I think you'll only get a strict subset of connected DAGs by forcing the subdiagonal to be one. There need not be a complete chain for it to be connected.

Comment: @Cardinal Thanks for the elegant example.  (You can tell I'm a beginner at `R`...).  Yes, not all DAGs have complete chains--see my first comment about using a random marked tree to cover all possibilities.  Another method is to topologically sort components of a random DAG and then merge those sorts at appropriate random points.  The difficulty is not generating all possible DAGs; it lies rather in figuring out their relative frequencies.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks. Elegant is a terrible overstatement, though. :) In all seriousness, every once in a while I blindly stumble upon a very useful `R` function that saves me some repetitive ad-hoc coding. The discovery of `lower.tri` was one of those. That said, for large graphs, something closer to yours will work better since we only need to take a sample of size $E$ from the set $\{1,\ldots,V(V-1)/2\}$.

Comment: @Cardinal My solution is not any more efficient: it has to compute a list of v(v-1)/2 indexes.  Yours has to generate a permutation of a list of that length, which only takes time directly proportional to the list length.

Comment: @whuber: Yes, but what I intended to convey was that something in the spirit of your approach would be more efficient, as hinted at near the end of my previous comment. :) We need only sample $E$ elements from a set of size $V(V-1)/2$ and there is a natural bijection between that and the indices of the lower diagonal of the associated array. I couldn't fit that in one line though. :)

Comment: @Cardinal I recognize that you were referring to the possibility $E << V^2$, but in the end the presence of the $O(V^2)$ operations renders that difference of little consequence: both algorithms scale quadratically with $V$; $E$ cannot scale any worse than that; and the `sample` operation creates an entire new copy of the adjacency matrix, anyway. :-).  But the computer is the ultimate arbiter: I am rather surprised to see your version of `DAG.random(10000,1)` takes nine times longer than my version of the same thing.  Replacing `1` by `5000` doesn't change anything.

Comment: I suppose I am being dense. I am sure I am misunderstanding something simple, but I do not see where the $O(V^2)$ operations you are counting are coming from? If I can sample without replacement in $O(1)$ time for each element, then I sample $O(E)$ elements and have to compute $O(E)$ indices.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3371/discussion-between-whuber-and-cardinal)